# Layer ARRA-CA_CentralCoast-Z3_2010_000006: Untwine error: unordered_map::at: key not found

Tags: qgis, lidar

[image]

Am getting an error while trying to load lidar data in qgis 3.4 is there a work around?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of QGIS - there will have been a lot of bugs fixed between 3.4 and 3.26